# What does the absence of hydrodynamic entrance effects do to the momentum conservation Equation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, energy-conservation, pressure, density

I am trying to do a homework problem where we re-write the mass, momentum and energy conservation formulas for downward flow in a vertical pipe and it says "where all hydrodynamic entrance effects have disappeared". What exactly does this mean? Also I am using an incompressible substance if that helps.

Someone told me this meant that $$\frac{\partial \vec V}{\partial z}=0$$ and $$\frac{\partial \vec V}{\partial t}=0$$

I don't see how the z-component of velocity doesn't change with time or with position in the z-direction if gravity is acting on the fluid particles. Gravity should be accelerating the fluid particles which means the z-component of velocity should change with time, and if its accelerating then shouldnt the profile also change?

Comment: Compare with the terminal velocity of an object falling through a fluid.

Comment: This is also commonly referred to as [fully developed flow](http://www.leb.eei.uni-erlangen.de/winterakademie/2006/result/content/course01/pdf/0110.pdf).

Comment: @Bernhard, I assuming you are hinting towards the fact velocity profile does not change with time or space. Am I right?

Comment: Also, Someone just tried to tell me that even thought the flow velocity profile does not change with time or space, the magnitude of the velocity does change

Comment: @GregHarrington That does not make sense

Comment: @GregHarrington By conservation of mass the magnitude of velocity cannot change if the velocity profile, area, and density are fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technical term for what you're looking for is "Fully developed flow". This means that the velocity does not change in the direction of the flow.

I'm going to explain for a horizontal pipe here, but it is just as valid for a vertical pipe.

[image]

When the flow just enters the pipe from a region of significantly larger cross section, the layers of the flow close to the wall are decelerated due to friction with the wall. This retardation creates a shear layer, where the fluid is slower than the rest of the fluid. As the flow "develops", this shear layer gets bigger until the entire area of the pipe has a velocity gradient.

Consider $P_1$, $P_2$, $P_3$, and $P_4$ to be four probes in the flow, which can measure the velocity without affecting it.

$P_1$ measures a uniform velocity profile entering the pipe. You can see the profile developing at $P_2$ and $P_3$. The blue area is the area with the unretarded fluid. The grey area is the shear layer, where there is a velocity in the radial direction (to maintain continuity). The green area is the fully developed area.

In a horizontal pipe flow, the flow is kept running by a pressure gradient. It becomes stable when the force due to the pressure gradient on the fluid element is equal to the force due to the shear forces on it. At this condition (in the green zone), because there is no net force on the fluid element, its velocity can not change with time.

$$\therefore \frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial t} = 0$$

Additionally, because the element moves along the pipe (I'm going to call this the $z$ direction), and its velocity does not change with time, its velocity stays the same with $z$.

$$\therefore \frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial z} = 0$$

When the pipe is vertical, gravity replaces (or supplements) the pressure gradient as the driving force. The shear force still balances this out in fully developed flow.

When we say ignore the "entrance effects", we mean ignore the blue and grey zones, and consider the flow in the green zone only.

Comment: this is awesome. Thank you. I have one more question. Assuming an axi-symmetric pipe, is there a fluid velocity in the theta direction when the flow is still developing? My professor said in an email that there is no fluid velocity in the theta direction when the flow is still developing but I don't see why this is. If there is no velocity in the theta direction when it is developing or when it is fully developed then is there ever a fluid velocity in the theta direction?

Comment: If the pipe was rotating, there could be. However, since there isn't any driving force in the $\theta$ direction, there's no motion at any time

Comment: Even though the flow is still developing? I know there is velocity in the radial direction while the flow is still developing so I figured there would also be velocity in the theta direction

Comment: Continuity requires there be some radial velocity in developing flow. Axisymmetry says that whatever flow in theta direction is seen at one section must persist throughout the theta direction, it doesn't say anything about the velocity itself. We know the velocity is zero because there is nothing to drive it, unlike the continuity condition which drives the radial component. Make sense to you?